# C# Gridview CheckBox Field VS (Template Field + CheckBox)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I got a `gridview` that pulls out a column of "Product" from the database.

With that, I would need a `checkbox` for the user to "checked" against each product in the `gridview` when it's finished.

I have research about **CheckBox Field VS (Template Field + CheckBox)** and decided to use **(Template Field + CheckBox)**  for the `gridview` to hold the `checkbox`.

GridView Column[0] = Product Name
GridView Column [1] = Checkbox

After "checking" some `checkboxes`, then the user click submit which would trigger the event below.

```
string checkedBy;        
foreach (GridViewRow row in grvCheckList.Rows)
{
   // Im not sure how to check if each checkbox has been "checked" 
   // or not as it is in the gridview  cell.

   // what I like to have is
      if((checkbox in column[1]).checked == true)
      { 
        checkedBy = // Staff name 
        // my codes to store the staff name into database with respective to the product listed in             the gridview row 
       }
      else
      { 
        checkedBy = "NULL"
        // my code to store "NULL" into database with respect to the product listed in the gridview        row
      }
}
```

For usual `checkbox`, what I normally do is below

```
if(checkbox1.checked == true ) 
else if(checkbox2.checked == true )
else if(checkbox3.checked == true )
etc
```

So the my question is how do I check if the `checkbox` in each row has been "checked" or not despite every row in the `gridview` uses the same `checkbox`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**CheckBox Field:**
must bound to a field of database and is read only.

**CheckBox in Template Field:**
Can use as a rocord selector.

Sample with template field:

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="fname" HeaderText="fname" SortExpression="fname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="lname" HeaderText="lname" SortExpression="lname" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (chk != null)
            {
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    // process selected record
                    Response.Write(item.Cells[1].Text + "<br>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```